# how to convert a string into url in python

Tags: python, url, urlencode

I have a string with the following format: `foo://bar_baz`.
I need to encode the entire string to be URL friendly. Right now I am doing it like so (as most answers seem to point):

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
mydict = {'q': 'foo://bar_baz'}
urlencode(mydic)
```

which returns:

```
'q=foo%3A%2F%2Fbar_baz'
```

I can use this without problem, but it seems counterintuitive / extra steps to have to define a dictionary, and assign a key (in this case `q`) that I will not be using.
Moreover, I need to go through the step of properly parsing the output to remove the `q=`
as I only need to encode the value for the key `q`. Spliting by `q=` could do it, but what if foo/bar/baz are actualy `fooq=` ? it might break stuff.

I was hoping to do something like:

```
# pass a string instead of a dict
encoded_string = urlencode("foo://bar_baz")
```

but that of course raises error.

Answer (score 5):

ok I just needed to google a bit more.

```
urllib.parse.quote_plus("foo://bar_baz")
```

did the trick.